# confuse about the parameter in starting the supervisord

Tags: php, supervisord

Can someone help me please, I am installing supervisor in centos. My problem is that when I start supervisord, I use this `supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf` then I can `supervisorctl start myapp:*`. and my background script is working, but if I do like this `service supervisord start`. it doen't work I can't use this command `supervisorctl start myapp:*` because it will raised up error `myapp: ERROR (no such group)`.

My problem is that when my server rebooted I cannot start my supervisor right away. I need to execute again `supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf`. can someone help me to fix this ***abnormal*** configuration please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your supervisord config? If not then try to use the script below..

$ sudo vi /etc/init.d/supervisord

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/init.d/functions

DAEMON=/usr/bin/supervisord
PIDFILE=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

start() {
        echo -n "Starting supervisord: "
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
                PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
                echo supervisord already running: $PID
                exit 2;
        else
                daemon  $DAEMON --pidfile=$PIDFILE -c /etc/supervisord.conf
                RETVAL=$?
                echo
                [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/supervisord
                return $RETVAL
        fi

}

stop() {
        echo -n "Shutting down supervisord: "
        echo
        killproc -p $PIDFILE supervisord
        echo
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/supervisord
        return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status supervisord
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage:  {start|stop|status|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Next, run the chkconfig command it allows to configure services start and stop automatically during start up in Linux.

```
$ chkconfig --add supervisord
$ chkconfig supervisord --level 345 on
```

For more references:
http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/04/enabling-and-disabling-services-during_01.html
https://serverfault.com/questions/96499/how-to-automatically-start-supervisord-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: I have the same issue - I have tried running "chkconfig --add supervisord" on the command line and receive "service supervisord does not support chkconfig"

Comment: have you install the supervisord in your system? If not follow this step: http://supervisord.org/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it -Make sure you have this at the top of your supervisord script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# /etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord
#
# Supervisor is a client/server system that
# allows its users to monitor and control a
# number of processes on UNIX-like operating
# systems.
#
# chkconfig: - 64 36
# description: Supervisor Server
# processname: supervisord
```

With these settings the script gets recognised correctly